# Token_storage in Symfony2 has no token

Tags: php, symfony, security, authentication, token

In Symfony2, I pass @security.token_storage to a listener that is registered as a service. I do this for multiple services.

In one case, the token_storage does not have a method getToken(). I don't understand why, as a user is logged in and other services can access it.

I registered my service like this:

```
gedmo.listener.loggable:
    class: CmdbBundle\Library\Loggable\LoggableListener
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: default }
    calls:
        - [ setAnnotationReader, [ @annotation_reader ] ]
        - [ setUserValue, [ @security.token_storage ] ]
```

I don't know why there is no token accessible. My dev bar shows that there is a token of the kind: UsernamePasswordToken.

My intention is to obtain the username of the user that is currently logged in. I need to make the service aware of that.

Comment: Are you calling getToken in setUserValue?  If so it is a timing issue.  Listeners themselves are created before the security stuff does it's stuff.  Call getToken when the listener actually receives an event.

Answer (score 0):

The service does not appear to be initialized, the attribute in your listener is probably null at the moment you try to to get the token.
I personally use constructor to construct services, in your case you must too try like this.
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#referencing-injecting-services

Because setters are made for optional services, and in your case the service seems mandatory.

```
gedmo.listener.loggable:
    class: CmdbBundle\Library\Loggable\LoggableListener
    arguments:
        - '@annotation_reader'
        - '@security.token_storage'
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: default }
```